# How to fix seed in hive

Tags: hive, seed, seeding

I am running an experiment and need to fix the audience for test and control group. Here is the query I am using:

```
 select consumer_id,
  case when rand(5555)<0.5 then 'control'
       else 'experiment' 
   end as groups
from my_table
```

If I create two tables using the same query, and join them, they have the same split but if I do join together in the same query it gives different split for each.

```
select a.groups,b.groups,count(*) from
 (select consumer_id,
  case when rand(5555)<0.5 then 'control'
       else 'experiment' 
   end as groups
from my_table) a
left join 
 (select consumer_id,
        case when rand(5555)<0.5 then 'control'
             else 'experiment' 
         end as groups
from my_table) b on a.consumer_id = b.consumer_id
group by a.groups,b.groups;
```

Any idea why is this and which function I can use for seeding in hive

Comment: Since there is a join, the "left" random() call might not get evaluated for some rows. If you create temp tables first using the same random filter, that should work. Although, in most scenarios using some kind of a hash function over customer_id with a mod is the way to go (e.g., hash(customer_id) mod 100 = 1). Perhaps, you don't even need a hash function if customer ids are "random".

Answer (score 0):

I found the same bug querying a table twice (nothing related to the join itself). Try setting

```
hive.optimize.index.filter=false;
```

Let me know if it works, if it does not I think there is one additional property with a bug querying a table twice.